# Why cant read newline and spaces with getchar()?

Tags: c

I need to let a user enter an input using getchar, and check for the number of spaces, newlines, and the other characters.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

    char word;
    int spaces, newLines, theRest;
    spaces = 0;
    newLines = 0;
    theRest = 0;
    printf("please type an input:\n");

    while ((word = getchar() != '#'))
    {
        if (word == ' ')
            spaces++;
        else if (word == '\n')
            newLines++;
        else
            theRest++;
    }
    printf("number of spaces: %d, number of new lines: %d, other characters: %d", spaces, newLines, theRest);

}
```

For any input i provide, im getting only `theRest` value, which includes all the characters.
Could you please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: [Operator precedence](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/operator.7.html). Inside that loop, `word` is always 1.

Comment: char word;
    word = getchar();

What's wrong with this? Suppose that "char" is equivelant to "signed char", and that EOF (which isn't a character) is -1. How do you differentiate between EOF and the character represented by -1?

getchar() returns int for a reason: It converts the char value to an *unsigned char* value, which means any successfully read character *will not* have a negative value. This means you can differentiate between the negative EOF and any positive character quite easily, *providing* you store the return value into an *int*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (word = getchar() != '#')
```

should be:

```
while ((word = getchar()) != '#')
```

Comment: @ErikNedwidek assignment (`=`) has lower precedence than `!=`. So that's the problem in OP's code because result of the comparison is stored in `word` which is always boolean. But the intention was to store the character. So what he has doesn't work.